# error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8

Tags: java, compiler-construction, utf-8

I receive this error when I try to compile a java project.unfortunately the error is present in over 262 files and I can't spend my time to correct in every file.does exist a faster way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

find out what encoding your source files have and pass that as -encoding argument to javac.